# Apache HIve 2.1.1 ERROR

Tags: hadoop, hive, derby

I have configured hive 2.1.1 with Hadoop 2.7.4. by following [this](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Hive_Install_On_Ubuntu_16_04.php) tutorial. When I start Hive shell, following exception appeared

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-2.1.1.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:558)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3406)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3640)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1652)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore. )
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.checkSchema(ObjectStore.java:7753)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.verifySchema(ObjectStore.java:7731)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:101)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.verifySchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:565)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:626)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
```

Where I am wrong ?

Comment: Can you provide output of hive --service schemaTool -dbType derby -info

Comment: Also, Are you able to connect to your derby database directly? Just to check derby connection is working. Also, paste the command you are running and with which user